# What is the use of the data type 'intp' in NumPy?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I've seen the data types in the NumPy package of Python, but I found the description of the data type 'intp' a bit confusing. Its description is like:

- intp: Integer used for indexing (same as C ssize_t; normally either int32 or int64)

Why is the word indexing used here if it is same as the ssize_t of C, as ssize_t is used to store the size of a variable?

Comment: "why the word indexing is used here if it is same as the ssize_t of C" - I would say it is used because it is same as the ssize_t of C :-) 32bit on 32bit system, 64bit on 64bit system, maybe there is some use case..

Comment: I've seen `intp` used in `cython` examples (and potentially other `c` interfaced code).  There's no point in using it as a `dtype` in `numpy` python code.

Comment: @JanStránský What does it mean by indexing?

Comment: Ok, so the actual question is "what does indexing mean in this context?"?

Comment: Does [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845707/2700104) answer your question? `ssize_t` is not "used to store the size of a variable", it is a size of a pointer, used in indexing the memory access